# 'Template' resource in chef is not creating the required file

Tags: chef-infra, chef-recipe

I am using the below code snippet in chef to create and copy the contents from
user_config_splunk.conf.erb to user-seed.conf. 
It is executed without any errors, but some how there is no file created in the specified path.

I see in the logs that there is removal of the original file and additional of a hidden file. Not sure what it means.

```
 +++ /opt/splunkforwarder/etc/system/local/.chef-user-seed20190510-3124-18cbkkv.conf  2019-05-10 20:33:46.913823000 +0000
```

Any idea?

**Chef Code**

```
   # Deploy the seeds file
    template '/opt/splunkforwarder/etc/system/local/user-seed.conf' do
        source 'user_config_splunk.conf.erb'
        owner 'root'
        group 'root'
        mode '0777'
        force_unlink false
    end
```

**Chef Logs**

```
 * template[/opt/splunkforwarder/etc/system/local/user-seed.conf] action create
           - create new file /opt/splunkforwarder/etc/system/local/user-seed.conf
           - update content in file /opt/splunkforwarder/etc/system/local/user-seed.conf from none to 35d6af
           --- /opt/splunkforwarder/etc/system/local/user-seed.conf     2019-05-10 20:33:46.913823000 +0000
           +++ /opt/splunkforwarder/etc/system/local/.chef-user-seed20190510-3124-18cbkkv.conf  2019-05-10 20:33:46.913823000 +0000
```

Answer (score 0):

from the chef-client log, it seems that a file has been created at `/opt/splunkforwarder/etc/system/local/user-seed.conf` and is owned by `root`. when you verify whether the file is there, make sure that you do that with a user that has a permission to access the file.

Comment: Even with root user, it doesnt show the file in the folder. @MrRoth

Comment: @Wings2fly: look closely at your cookbook run-list, feels like something else is "deleting' the file